# Including DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE in environment variable on Windows

Tags: python, django, windows

Please, how do I include `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` in my environment variable so that I won't be using cd myproject before I could run any command in the terminal; below is my setting in the environment variable.

```
C:\Users\Freddy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32;C:\Users\Freddy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts
```

Comment: https://www.forbeslindesay.co.uk/post/42833119552/permanently-set-environment-variables-on-windows

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` just to avoid doing `cd myproject`. What will you do when you start a second project? `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` can only point to one of your projects. If you're new to Django, it's easier if you follow the same approach as most other users, and that means using `manage.py`.

Comment: Okay Alasdair,your advice is taken. Thanks.